# How to consolidate a DF into individual rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF of the following format:

```
Match | Bookmaker | Over/Under Type | Over 1,5 | Under 1,5 | Over 2 | Under 2 

A vs B | Asianodds| 1,5             | 2,11     | 1,26      | n/a    |  n/a

A vs B | Pinnacle | 1,5             | 2,11     | 1,26      | n/a    |  n/a

A vs B | Asianodds| 2               |   n/a    | n/a       | 3,2    | 1,32   

A vs B | Pinnacle | 2               |   n/a    | n/a       | 3,3    | 1,42

C vs D | Asianodds| 1,5             | 2,31     | 1,25      | n/a    | n/a

C vs D | Pinnacle | 1,5             | 2,71     | 1,76      | n/a    | n/a

C vs D | Asianodds| 2               | n/a      |n/a        | 3,4    | 1,34

C vs D | Pinnacle | 2               | n/a      |n/a        | 3,5    | 1,45
```

How can I manipulate the DF to get to this format (one line per Match/Bookmaker):

```
Match | Bookmaker | Over 1,5 | Under 1,5 | Over 2 | Under 2 | 

A vs B | Asianodds| 2,11     | 1,26      | 3,2    | 1,32

A vs B | Pinnacle | 2,11     | 1,26      | 3,3    | 1,42 

C vs D | Asianodds| 2,31     | 1,25      | 3,4    | 1,34   

C vs D | Pinnacle | 2,71     | 1,76      | 3,5    | 1,45
```

Comment: Pls explain how you want to consolidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `'Over/Under Type` column and then use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non missing values per groups:

```
df = df.drop('Over/Under Type', 1).groupby(['Match','Bookmaker'], as_index=False).first()
print (df)
    Match  Bookmaker Over 1,5 Under 1,5 Over 2 Under 2
0  A vs B  Asianodds     2,11      1,26    3,2    1,32
1  A vs B   Pinnacle     2,11      1,26    3,3    1,42
2  C vs D  Asianodds     2,31      1,25    3,4    1,34
3  C vs D   Pinnacle     2,71      1,76    3,5    1,45
```

Comment: Somehow this did not quite do the trick yet, the DF still looks like before.. what could be wrong?

Comment: @BlackElefant Are `n/a` missing values? Maybe need `df=df.replace('n/a',np.nan)` before my solution.

Comment: Actually it did work out, I just didnt apply it in the right place of the loop. Thanks for the solution!